# BASYS2 - Verilog: how to properly edit ucf file?

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, spartan-3

I am a newbie at FPGA. I bought BASYS2 digilent board(Spartan3E). I have background on microcontrollers. C/C++ is no problem for me. But I am having some 
trouble with FPGA. Actually, not with FPGA but with Compiler and ISE. As 
you can see in the screenshot below, I configured the FPGA chip.

[image: FPGA Verilog screenshot]

This is the implementation code:

```
module myModule(A, B);
    input wire A;
    output wire B;
    assign B = !A;

endmodule
```

And this is the ucf code:

```
# Onboard LEDs
NET "B" LOC = "M11";

NET "A" LOC = "C11";
```

As boards technical sheet says, M11 is LED 1 and C11 is BTN 2. So I want 
LED to flash when I unpress the button. Do you see something wrong with 
the code? Because it aint working. If the code should have been working, 
what should I do? Am I skipping something?

[image: Pinouts]

As you see I aldready generated programming file and run. So what next?

Thanks.

Comment: The schematic shows C11 as BTN1 not BTN2...

Comment: How do you mean, "run"?   Do you mean you opened Impact and followed the necessary steps?  Every thing else is fine

Comment: As long as your hitting the right button @Brian Drummond

Answer (score 1):

Go to **project**->**Design Properties** and under **Project Settings** make sure that everything is configured correctly for the BASYS2. Make sure you have the correct family and device selected.

I've attached an image which I believe has the correct settings for your board. Check to make sure yours match!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have selected the correct board or the FPGA that is one very common mistake beginners make. Follow the link and download master ucf file for BASYS 2 board edit the UCF file as per your needs.

http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavTop=2&NavSub=457&Prod=BASYS&CFID=22755330&CFTOKEN=47b4ab0f6ca91a31-547AD8AE-5056-0201-025036B4038D0C97